# Deploying ionic 2 application for testing purposes

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic2, visual-studio-cordova

I am developing `Hybrid Mobile Application` using the following tools `ionic 2 with angular 2 and typescript` in `visual studio 2015`

I can run the application in development environment using `ionic serve` to run locally or `ionic build android` to create an `apk` for android

Now we are preparing for testing phase so we want to test against a punch of platform and devices. We cannot afford all these devices in order to test our application. We thought on finding a tool to simulate the device for both IOS and Android.

Any suggestions on how we can test our application? Do we depend on emulators or we should buy all this devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could try a tool called Geny Motion. It allows you to simulate your app in different devices and it's widely used (instead of the default Android emulator). As for iOS you could simulate your app in your mac itself (in different iOS versions).

Comment: so, you think emulators are enough for testing mobile applications or should we depend on any other methodology?!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for mobile device testing in the cloud.

Here are a couple of options (I'm sure there are more out there, but a start...)

- AWS Device Farm: https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/
- Xamarin Test Cloud: (you can test Hybrid apps using Calabash) https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/choosing-a-framework/